# Differentials on a hyper elliptic curve that are preserved by involution can be pulled back from $\mathbb{P}^1$ from $\pi$, hence must be 0.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

This is the exercise 21.3.C from FOAG. I did the first two, but got stuck at the third one. I'm not entirely sure what it's asking.

Given a double cover $\pi: C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ branched over $2g+2$ distinct points. Show that $h^0(C,\Omega_{C/k}) = g$ as follows.

1. Show that $\frac{dx}{y}$ is a (regular) differential on $\mathrm{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2 - f(x))$, i.e. an element of $\Omega_{(k[x,y]/(y^2 - f(x)))/k}$.
2. Show that for $0\leqslant i < g$, $x^i \frac{dx}{y}$ extends to a global differential $\omega_i$ on $C$, i.e. with no poles.
3. Use (1) to show that any differential $\omega\in H^0(C,\Omega_{C/k})$ preserved by the involution $i:y\mapsto -y$ must be pulled back from $\mathbb{P}^1$ by $\pi$, and hence must be zero. Show that every differential $\omega\in H^0(C,\Omega_{C/k})$ satisfies $i^*\omega = -\omega$.

Comment: It looks like $C$ is endowed with an involution $i$. Is this part of the assumptions?

Comment: Yes. $C$ is a hyper elliptic curve. So it has a natural involution $I$.

Comment: Here is a way to do 3. By the Lefschetz fixed point formula, we have $2-2(g_+-g_{-})=2g+2$, where $g_+$ (resp. $g_{-}$) is the dimension of the $1$-eigenspace (resp. $-1$-eigenspace) of $i^*:H^{0}(C,\Omega_{C/k})\to H^{0}(C,\Omega_{C/k}).$ So we have $g_{-}-g_+=g$. On the other hand, the RH  formula gives $2(g_{-}+g_+)-2=2(-2)+2g+2=2g-2$ and so $g_{-}+g_+=g$. In particular, the genus of $C$ is $g$ (you don't need the fixed point formula for this) and $g_{+}=0.$

Comment: @DamianRössler Hi. What version of the Lefschetz fixed point formula is used?